# what is the difference in using regex between split() and contains() in java

Tags: java, regex

I am studying regex in Java. After I do some reading I think `|` is a special character in regex, but when I try to apply these two functions I find that I can directly use `|` in contains function, which should be in the format `\\|` in split function. so is there any difference in these two functions in apply regex?

```
String c = "come|dra";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("|");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(c);

System.out.println(matcher.find()+" "+c.contains("|"));
String [] s1 = c.split("|");
System.out.println(s1[1]);
```

output:

> ```
> true true
> c
> ```

Comment: Please add the output

Comment: @hwnd i just think it use it, i think i miss some part in documentation. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful which methods you're calling.  In your example code, you're calling [`String.contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) which does not use regular expressions.

> Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.

Certain methods of `String` - namely [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-), [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), [`String.replaceFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), and [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) - are convenient wrappers around the regular expression behaviour [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) provides.  For example, `String.split()` simply* calls:

> ```
> return Pattern.compile(regex).split(this, limit);
> ```

<sup>* It actually tries to do some optimizations before reaching this line, but in the general case, that's what it does.</sup>

Comment: get it, i think i must miss some reading part, that make think contains function use regular expression. thank you and accept

Comment: In general, you should expect operations on `String` to work with *exactly* what you pass in.  Only the methods that explicitly say they expect regular expressions will do otherwise, and generally they simply wrap behaviour `Pattern` provides.

Comment: one more question, why I don't need a double backslash in compile() which need a regex inside? Which situation do I need to use double backslash in that kind of function?

Comment: You need a double backslash any time your regular expression requires a single backslash.  When you write `"\\"` Java creates a String containing a single character, `\`.  Since (somewhat confusingly) `Pattern` *also* uses backslashes as escape characters, regular expressions in Java often end up with lots of backslashes.  [This site](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) lets you test your expressions without Java escaping, and prints out a Java string literal you can use with the correct double-backslashing.

Comment: Also, in general, please post a new question rather than asking followup questions in comments - this way everyone can benefit from your question.

Answer (score 1):

The **`#String.contains()`** method works with only "String". It doesn't work with regular expressions, while the **`#String.split()`** method can split  using regular expression as delimiter.